# Apache Tapestry 5 property binding - ERROR

Tags: java, apache, binding, properties, tapestry

Helo. I am having problem binding a property from code behind to frontend and can't seem to figure out what is the problem.

The code behind is the following (Layout.java)

```
private String userEmail;

public String getUserEmail()
{
    userEmail = getUser() == null ? "Not logged in" : getUser().getName();
    return userEmail;
}

public Users getUser()
{
    return login.isLoggedIn() ? login.getLoggedUser() : null;
}
```

This how i am trying to display it in the .tml file (Layout.tml):

```
${userEmail}
```

If for example, in the `getUserEmail()` function i just return a simple string, it is displayed. When i do it like this, i get the following error:

```
org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.internal.OperationException
Render queue error in Expansion[PropBinding[expansion Index:layout(userEmail)]]: org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.internal.util.TapestryException
```

Could anyone please tell what i am doing wrong?

Best regards, Marius.

Answer (score 1):

Not without a bit more of the exception.

Also, read up on JavaBeans properties; you don't need a userEmail field to have a userEmail property, you just need the getter (for this kind of computed-on-the-fly, read-only property).